# Python configuration flawed due to interferences of several user accounts, python versions and package managers. (import requests not found)

Tags: python, macos, python-requests, package-managers, user-accounts

I have the following problem: I can't import the requests package and I've tried already a lot of stuff, however without any useful results. Due to the online research I've done I assume one of the following reasons or a combination of them:

- different MAC user accounts interfere with each other
- python2 VS python3
- pip VS anaconda (I've had Anaconda installed earlier and uninstalled it hoping that it might resolve this problem...)

Here's a few of the things that I tried:

```
pip install requests
```

However, the result was the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] 
Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.25.6.dist- 
info' Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.
```

Next try:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

A warning, but the packages are installed:

```
WARNING: The directory '/Users/cuezumo/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its 
parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been 
disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If 
executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
....
Installing collected packages: urllib3, certifi, chardet, idna, requests
Successfully installed certifi-2019.9.11 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 requests- 
2.22.0 urllib3-1.25.6
```

Then, however, the import doesn't work:

```
import requests
```

leads to

```
command not found: import
```

Can anybody offer some support? I'm sorry if this is not yet enough information for you to provide help. I'm happy to provide you with more information if you can tell me what you need and how I can retrieve it.

ad various mac user accounts:
I'd like to delete the second user account, because I don't need it anymore. Thus, if resetting the python environment would be necessary in any way for the resolution of this issue, this account could be deleted along the way.

Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? It does not look like the case.  Very few things should ever be installed outside of a virt environment. Anaconda leaves a heavy and difficult to remove footprint as well as setting up some "handy" default operation that will throw even experienced Python devs in a loop.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your answer. No, I checked again and there's no virtual environment installed. Would it make sense to reinstall Anaconda?

Comment: A virtual env stands to solve your problem and [opinion] should be used 100% of the time for any local development.  As for anaconda [opinion again] - if you can avoid it you will be better off, this view varies.  Right now I use PIPENV for package management and VENV.  Despite PIPENV imperfections, with a little knowledge of bash and a Pythonic mindset problems should be minor.  Conda has never performed well for me, my teams, or the data science projects in my 10+ years of Python. Try PIPENV or VENV via Python3, DM for some tips.